# Getting value from <input type='file'> returns empty string

Tags: javascript, input-type-file

I am making a portlet and have a file uploader there. I should get the name of the file that is uploaded by the means of js.

The HTML code:

```
<form id="theuploadform" onsubmit = "javascript:setTimeout('fileupload_ajax_query_upload_status', 1000);"; action=<portlet:resourceURL/> method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data" target="postiframe">
    <input id="userfile" name="userfile" size="50" type="file" /> 
    <input id="formsubmit" type="submit" value="Upload to server" onclick="handleUploadDialogClose2();" />
</form>
```

And the js part:

```
function handleUploadDialogClose2() {
    var filepath = document.getElementById("userfile").value;
    alert(filepath);
}
```

I select a file to upload, click "Upload to server" button and check the value of input element - it is empty. But I saw quite similar code in the other questions here and it worked.
What should I do to get it work?

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
function handleUploadDialogClose2() {
  var filepath = document.getElementById("userfile").files[0];
  console.log(filepath);
}
```

working example: [js.bin](http://jsbin.com/OzExIyaS/1/edit)

Comment: This doesn't help too. I tried this yesterday and got `undefined`.

Comment: ok, what i think the problem is, is the missing quotes on action attribute. It should be: action="<portlet:resourceURL/>";

Comment: Quotes doesn't have any effect on this. I saw your example and it is ok, but I cannot guess what's wrong in my case.

Comment: The most interesting thing is that my code works well at JSBin, but doesn't work at all at my development portal.

Comment: The only thing i noticed, is that when you don't put quotes after action property in hmtl editor it breaks the dom model and thats why you get empty value. Can you investigate the dom model in your development portal?

Answer (score 0):

You may try removing the `semi-colon` after the `onsubmit` attribute in the form. It should not be like:

```
onsubmit = "javascript:setTimeout('fileupload_ajax_query_upload_status', 1000);";
```

But should be like:

```
onsubmit = "javascript:setTimeout('fileupload_ajax_query_upload_status', 1000);"
```

You may also create a separate function which calls `setTimeout()` rather than putting the function call in the attribute.

Hope this helps you get the issue sorted!

Comment: Thanks. Upload status is not my part of a code and I missed this. But anyway this is not an issue and have zero effect.